# Recommendation for database for a search engine

Tags: database

I am writing a search engine i am looking for a database to store all my crawled datas which will be used for URLDatabase and Data store.

1. It should be disk based not memory based
2. Java preferable because my application is in java so that i can
   easily embedded it.
3. Salable
4. Preferred for Linux and windows.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Hadoop and HBase

http://hadoop.apache.org/

http://hbase.apache.org/

Comment: Okay Does it support windows?

Comment: In the way that you want to setup Hadoop on Windows ?

Comment: I am just reading its wiki it has a standalone version http://hbase.apache.org/book/standalone_dist.html .Does it need linux?

Comment: You could try on Windows for development, but it is not recommended as a production platform

Comment: Okey Thankyou i have a ubuntu box i will try in that.

Answer (score 0):

I really like [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), which is a thin java wrapper on [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/), which is very a widely used, extreme-performance, text-based, nosql database (possibly the *most* widely used).

It is ridiculously fast (millisecond response) at finding matches and you can sort the results as you get them.

It is super easy to set up, runs under tomcat, uses plain old disk files and runs under both linux and windows, so it meets all your requirements.

I've used it on several projects and it was always successful.

Comment: I am aware of lucene and solr . My plan is to use the lucene as search library and to store all the datas in a database  so i am searching a database. I would like to separate some data's from the index so i prefer that.